# Fast way to fill NaN in DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have `DataFrame` object `df` with column like that:

```
[In]: df
[Out]:
                 id            sum
0                 1            NaN
1                 1            NaN
2                 1              2
3                 1            NaN
4                 1              4
5                 1            NaN
6                 2            NaN
7                 2            NaN
8                 2              3
9                 2            NaN
10                2              8
10                2            NaN
...             ...            ...
[1810601 rows x 2 columns]
```

I have a lot a `NaN` values in my column and I want to fill these in the following way:

- if `NaN` is on the beginning (for first `index` per `id` equals `0`), then it should be `0`
- else if `NaN` I want take value from previous index for the same `id`

Output should be like that:

```
[In]: df
[Out]:
                 id            sum
0                 1              0
1                 1              0
2                 1              2
3                 1              2
4                 1              4
5                 1              4
6                 2              0
7                 2              0
8                 2              3
9                 2              3
10                2              8
10                2              8
...             ...            ...
[1810601 rows x 2 columns]
```

I tried to do it "step by step" using loop with `iterrows()`, but it is very ineffective method. I believe it can be done faster with pandas methods

Comment: Pandas has a function for that! Take a look at `pandas.DataFrame.fillna`.

Comment: But how can I use `pandas.DataFrame.fillna` for that specific condition?

Comment: @Justin `fillna` will not support conditional filling

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try ffill as suggested with groupby

```
df['sum'] = df.groupby('id')['sum'].ffill().fillna(0)
```